# Need Help Performing Derived Column Split in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

So in my Source Table from Excel I have a Column called `real/min/max` that counts population and I want to split this into 3 columns called `ActualPop`, `MinPop`, `MaxPop`.

So an example would be

```
real/min/max 

33/1/50
```

And I would need this to populate in the new Columns as

```
ActualPop  

33

MinPop

1

MaxPop

50
```

I tried the following Expressions:

ActualPop: `TOKEN([real/min/max],"/",1)`

MinPop: `TOKEN([real/min/max],"/",2)`

MaxPop: `TOKEN([real/min/max],"/",3)`

The issue is when I try to do my mapping to the SQL destination, I get an error about the Data Types. The destination has `INT` data types mean while in the Derived Column Editor I see the Data Types are Unicode String. I have tried to use the Data Conversion but that still does not work.

Comment: Would it be possible to use tab-delimited file as a source instead of excel file ? This might help ...

Answer (score 0):

You can change the data type of the 3 derived columns using the **Advanced Editor** on the **Derived Column**.

[image]

#### then.... select `four-byte signed integer [DT_I4]` for each of your `INT`s.

[image]

#### See: [Changing Datatype in SSIS Derived column](http://sql-biperformance.blogspot.com/2013/04/changing-datatype-in-ssis-derived-column.html)